# I need an explanation on access tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am currently trying to implement auth using Google API. What I don't understand what do I need the access token, that google provides me with, for. For my application I create a cookie after successful authentication via google so I have no purpose for access or refresh tokens. So what do I need them for?

As I understand this concept after `user` authenticate with google my API receive this 2 tokens for future access to not my API but the Google Services under the identity of my `user`. So I don't really need to manage tokens or consume them at any way. Am I right?

Comment: The way you're describing your app, you don't seem to need them. However, if you didn't create your own cookie that essentialy says that the user is loggen in forever, you could use the access and refresh tokens instead. That way, when the user signs out of all apps from their google account, they'll sign out of you app, too.